# Electron build cannot run with angular build properly

Tags: angular, electron, operating-system

I have electron app that runs on angular enviroment.
`electron: 22.3.27`
`electron-builder: 23.0.2`
`@angular/cli: 8.3.25`
`electron:windows32: npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --windows --ia32`

when application are runs first time that shows white screen / Blank screen i did suffered lots for that problem and after that i am tired this below way. Thats works, but when some system are slow.
then this will shows blank screen again and when i am kill application and run again that will work perfectly.

```
setTimeout(() => {
   createWindow();
}, 2000)
```

my `createWindow()` function looks like

```
const createWindow = async () => {
  console.log("CREATE WINDOW CALLS");
  const electronScreen = screen;
  const size = electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
  nativeTheme.themeSource = 'light';
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    show: silent ? false : true,
    // autoHideMenuBar: true,
    skipTaskbar: true,
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    width: 500,
    height: 650,
    icon: os.type() == "Linux" ? path.join(__dirname, "/angular_build/assets/app-256X256.png") : path.join(__dirname, "/angular_build/favicon.ico"),
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      devTools: true,
      allowRunningInsecureContent: serve ? true : false,
      contextIsolation: false,
      webSecurity: false
    },
    darkTheme: false,
    resizable: false
  });


  // win.webContents.send("reload-page")

  if (serve) {
    console.log("Serving the data :check==================================", serve);
    require("electron-reload")(__dirname, {
      electron: require(`${__dirname}/node_modules/electron`),
    });
    win.loadURL("http://localhost:4200");
    win.webContents.openDevTools();
  } else {

    setTimeout(() => {
      win.loadFile("./angular_build/index.html");
    }, 1000);

    // win.loadURL(
    //   url.format({
    //     pathname: path.join(__dirname,  "angular_build", "index.html"),
    //     protocol: "file:",
    //     slashes: true,
    //   })
    // );


    console.log(desktopCapturer, "desktopCapturer============ create window")

    powerMonitor.on('lock-screen', () => {
      console.log("LOCK SCREEN :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::")
      if (isWorking) {
        appendLastLogInFile("lock-screen");
      }
    });

    powerMonitor.on("suspend", () => {
      console.log("SUSPEND :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::")
      if (isWorking) {
        appendLastLogInFile("suspend");
      }
    });

    powerMonitor.on("resume", async () => {
      win.webContents.send("start", "Unlock successfully!");
    });

    powerMonitor.addListener("shutdown", () => {
      console.log("SHUTDOWN :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::")
      if (isWorking) {
        appendLastLogInFile("shutdown");
      }
    });

    powerMonitor.addListener("unlock-screen", () => {
      if (!win.isDestroyed()) {
        win.webContents.send("start", "Unlock successfully!");
      }
    });

    // Disable refresh
    win.on("focus", (event) => {
      console.log("event of on fucous ");
      electronLocalshortcut.register(
        win,
        ["CommandOrControl+R", "CommandOrControl+Shift+R", "F5"],
        () => { }
      );
    });

    win.on("blur", (event) => {
      console.log("event of on blue ");
      electronLocalshortcut.unregisterAll(win);
    });
    // debug
    // win.webContents.openDevTools()

  }

  if (serve) {
    win.webContents.openDevTools();
  }

  win.webContents.on("did-finish-load", () => {
    if (!win.isDestroyed()) {
      win.webContents.setBackgroundThrottling(false);
    }
  });

  win.on("close", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    win.hide();
    console.log("CLOSE ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ");
    // win.minimize();

    // win.webContents.send("closeCheckOnLogin");
    // console.log("close");
    // if (isWorking) {
    //   e.preventDefault();
    //   appendLastLogInFile("appClose");
    // }
    // else { }
  });
  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on("closed", () => {
    console.log("CLOSEd ");
    // if (!window.isDestroyed()) {
    //   window.close();
    // }
    console.log("closed");
  });



  // Emitted when the window is closed.

  win.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true);
  // win.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
  setCustomeMenu();
  return win;
}
```

my package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "MYAPP",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "angular 8",
    "electron",
    "typescript",
    "eslint",
    "spectron",
    "sass"
  ],
  "main": "main.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p ng:serve electron:serve ---isSilent=false",
    "build": "npm run electron:serve-tsc  && ng build ",
    "build:dev": "npm run build -- -c dev",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- -c production",
    "ng:serve": "ng serve",
    "ng:serve:web": "ng serve -c web -o",
    "electron:serve-tsc": "tsc -p tsconfig-serve.json",
    "electron:serve": "wait-on http-get://localhost:4200/ && npm run electron:serve-tsc && electron . --serve --no-sandbox",
    "electron:local": "npm run build:prod && electron .",
    "electron:linux": "npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --linux",
    "electron:linux32": "npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --linux --ia32",
    "electron:windows": "npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --windows",
    "electron:windows32": "npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --windows --ia32",
    "electron:mac": "npm run build:prod && electron-builder build --mac",
    "test": "ng test",
    "e2e": "npm run build:prod && mocha --timeout 300000 --require ts-node/register e2e/**/*.spec.ts",
    "version": "conventional-changelog -i CHANGELOG.md -s -r 0 && git add CHANGELOG.md",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "publish": {
    "provider": "github",
    "releaseType": "release"
  },
  "build": {
    "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "src/assets/",
        "to": "assets"
      }
    ],
    "asar": true,
    "directories": {
      "output": "dist"
    },
    "mac" : {
      "icon": "icon/app.icns"
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": "AppImage",
      "icon": "icon/app-256X256.png",
      "category": "Utility"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "icon/icon-new.ico"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "allowElevation": true,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": true
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "8.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.803.25",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "0.0.1-alpha.17",
    "@angular/cli": "8.3.25",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/service-worker": "8.2.14",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.3.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/jquery": "3.5.16",
    "@types/mocha": "5.2.7",
    "@types/node": "12.6.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.7.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.7.4",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "2.2.2",
    "core-js": "3.1.4",
    "electron": "22.3.27",
    "electron-builder": "23.0.2",
    "electron-reload": "2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "electron-reloader": "1.2.3",
    "eslint": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "karma": "6.4.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.1",
    "karma-electron": "7.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.2",
    "mocha": "10.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "rxjs": "^7.0.0",
    "spectron": "19.0.0",
    "ts-node": "8.3.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.3",
    "wait-on": "7.0.1",
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.1.9",
    "zone.js": "0.11.8"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 16.14.0 || >= 18.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0-0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/fire": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "8.2.3",
    "@angular/pwa": "12.1.4",
    "@electron/remote": "2.0.12",
    "active-win": "8.1.1",
    "auto-launch": "5.0.6",
    "axios": "1.5.1",
    "circular-json": "0.5.9",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "electron-browser-storage": "1.0.7",
    "electron-google-analytics4": "1.1.1",
    "electron-localshortcut": "3.2.1",
    "electron-progressbar": "2.1.0",
    "electron-store": "8.1.0",
    "electron-updater": "^6.1.4",
    "file-system": "1.2.2",
    "firebase": "7.24.0",
    "firebase-admin": "11.11.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "node-cron": "3.0.2",
    "node-gyp": "9.3.1",
    "uuidv7": "0.6.3",
    "pidusage": "3.0.2",
    "prebuild-install": "7.1.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.6.7",
    "sass": "^1.69.0",
    "simple-peer": "^9.11.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.2",
    "sweetalert2": "11.6.13",
    "ws": "^8.14.2"
  }
}
```

I am looking for reasone for why that will shows blank screen.